# How to remove repository name from a custom domain hosted in Github Pages?

Tags: github-pages, web-hosting, namecheap

I have made a NameCheap domain and linked it to GitHub pages properly.
If the site is live at a.me/resume, how can I make it just a.me and remove the repository's name from the url?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the repository and go to settings - pages - scroll down to the custom domain section and enter your custom domain and click save. You'll want to delete the old CNAME because when you save the custom domain it should create a new CNAME automatically.

I would also recommend verifying the custom domain you want to use with GitHub if you haven't already done so as a preventative measure to discourage domain squatters from using it. For that you'll just need to go to your account settings - pages - add a domain.

In order to verify the custom domain with GitHub, you'll need to add the verification code they give you to your DNS configuration as a TXT file.

https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/verifying-your-custom-domain-for-github-pages